# How can you filter model objects by attributes of their supermodel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-tests

To get started with Django I did the intro provided by Django itself. In part 5 of it, you write some `tests` for `views` and `models`. After that, they provide you with ideas for more `tests`. There is where my problem starts. They suggest you to only show `Questions` with a number of `Choices` greater than 0. I have no idea how to do that. My current code can be found at https://github.com/byTreneib/django.git. The Django tutorial can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return timezone.now() >= self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import F
from .models import Question, Choice
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).filter().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question, 'error_message': "No choice selected!"})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes = F('votes') + 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id, )))
```

Comment: Can you please make this question more self-contained, by providing some models, and specify what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I forgot to add the link to the django tutorial. It is provided now. There you can see what exactly the problem is. The code can be found at the github repo linked

Comment: Just added code of models.py and views.py . I hope everything comes clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all `Choice` instances pointing to a `Question` using django's `RelatedManager`. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/).

The view would be something like this:

```
class ListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(choice__isnull = False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will test it as soon as possible and then confirm whether it worked for me or not.